# Partition planar graph into connected subgraphs of equal size

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, partition-problem

Work

Jünger, Michael, Gerhard Reinelt, and William R. Pulleyblank. "On partitioning the edges of graphs into connected subgraphs." Journal of graph theory 9.4 (1985): 539-549.

states that for 4-edge-connected graph one can partition its edges into disjoint subsets of size $r$, such that each subset form a connected subgraph.

I wonder if the same kind of statement could be formulated for partition of vertices.
For what kind of graphs one find partition of vertices into disjoint subsets of size $\approx r$, such that each subset form a connected subgraph (for each r)? I'm particularly interested in planar graphs, but would be happy with any class.

I can soften some conditions (it will still meet my needs): for what graph classes existence of partition into less than $\frac{\alpha n}{r}$ connected subgraphs of size less than $r$ is guaranteed (for some $\alpha$)?

Comment: Compute planer embedding. Run some kind of [sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm). Once sweep line hits n/r vertices cut the edges connecting to the rest of the graph. This should work for planer graphs.

Comment: Well, you can't do this partition for any planar graph: for example star-graph is planar, but it is impossible to cut it into pieces of size more then 1.

Comment: I see. This makes the question very interesting. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute a constant degree spanning tree $T$ of your graph, root it, and now greedily find subtrees of roughly size $r$, extract them, and repeat. Naturally, if there is no constant degree spanning tree, then the star example shown above demonstrates that this algorithm can fail.

Answer (score 9):

For a graph $G=(V,E)$, deciding if $V$ can be partitioned into equal sized subsets (say, for a fixed size $r$) where each subset induces a connected subgraph is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. It remains $\mathsf{NP}$-hard for planar graphs, and also if the number of subsets is fixed instead of the subset size ($|V|/r$ fixed).

However, the problem is polynomial for cycles, and thus for Hamiltonian graphs. It is also polynomial for trees and for series-parallel graphs when the number of subsets is fixed.

You can find these results in:

- M. E. Dyer and A. M. Frieze. [On the complexity of partitioning graphs into connected subgraphs](http://math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Texfiles/COMPLEXPART.pdf).  Discrete Applied Mathematics, 10(2), 139-153. 1985.
- N. Apollonio & al. [Bicolored graph partitioning, or: gerrymandering at its worst](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X09002637).  Discrete Applied Mathematics, 157(17), 3601-3614. 2009.

Edit (bis): <s>I think that I was wrong about Hamiltonian graphs. They may be partitioned even if their Hamiltonian cycle cannot. Thus the problem can be not polynomial.</s> See the first comment.

Comment: Looks like you can do it for Hamiltonian graph. As this graph has a Hamiltonian graph, it has a spanning tree of max degree 2. It is possible to find a spanning tree of max degree 3 in polynomial time and using this tree partition the graph (as stated in other answer).

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/mohits/publications/approximating_minimum_bounded_degree_spanning_tree_to_within_one_of_optimal.pdf